# Magento 2:- How to call a js file on homepage?

Tags: magento2, javascript, home-page

I want to call a `js` file on `homepage` only how to to do that. Right now i am calling

`<head><link src="js/myfile.js"/></head>`

But it is calling for all page and give error `js error` on other pages. I am creating a custom theme.

Comment: It's very strange request for me. Can you describe more why you need only js on this page

Comment: @KAndy i got the solution myself will answer soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two way to do it.

1.first you add it from admin panel. `content->page -> edit page` in `design` tab  `Layout Update XML`

```
    <head><script src="js/myfile.js"/></head>
```

2. if your js is based on some js library.

`app/design/frontend/yourspacename/yourtheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
 <head><script src="js/myfile.js"/></head>
```

Comment: Sadly i got error adding from admin panel. `Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'head': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move )`

Comment: @Volvox you are adding this in design tab?

Comment: if this is not working add it with `<head><link src="js/myfile.js"/></head>`

Comment: Yes, this error appear when I add `<head><link src="js/myfile.js"/></head>`  in `Layout Update XML` on `Design` tab. Maybe it does not work in new versions, because here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126646/magento2-how-to-add-different-custom-css-file-on-specific-cms-pages someone gave similar solution, and got similar response.

Comment: @Volvox i tested it with 2.0. maybe version reasoning

Comment: I am using 2.1.7 and I have the same problem than @Volvox . Does anyone have solution excluding a rewrite module ?

Comment: Hi @QaisarSatti How to stop external API js file on the home page? please advice?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104684/how-to-add-external-js-in-magento-2

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280039/how-to-stop-calling-paypal-objects-file-on-home-page  can u please help me on this

Answer (score 2):

You can call your `js` only on home page by adding `cms_index_index.xml` file into your layout directory and your module directory structure should be

app/code/YOUR_NAMESPACE/YOUR_MODULENAME/view/frontend/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head><link src="js/myfile.js"/></head> 
</page>
```

Comment: i am creating a custom theme.

Comment: Where do you put the js file? And if you put it in your theme under web/js how do you reference it there?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include a javascript file from your theme into a cms page or block, you can use the built in `x-magento-init` system. This will remove the need to use xml or placing anything in the head of the page.

Inside of the cms block or page, place in these lines:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
         "Magento_Theme/js/custom-file": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

This is unique to Magento 2 and is a way of initializing Javascript by Magento and not the browser. [Alan Storm goes into depth on this issue here.](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts/) But the basic idea is you have Magento trigger off the execution of Javascript.

You pass in the DOM node you want to target (in this case we are targeting the whole page with `*`). You then pass in the path to the file you want to include. For us, we are passing in `Magento_Theme/js/custom-file` which will resolve to:

> app/design/frontend/{Namespace}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/custom-file.js

Note that you are using the Magento shorthand here, where the path ditches the `.js` file ext and then `web` dir, this can trip you up sometimes.

Inside the custom file you need to use require JS in the file to prevent conflicts. There are a few different ways to do this, but this works for me:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    return function () {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this-

```
<head>
<script src="Namespace_Modulename::js/theViewer.min.js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom module, and you want to add your JS file you can do as @Keyur suggests.

**If you want to include it from a custom Theme, do the following:**

1) Add your JS file in app/design/frontend/Kapisharp/wildernessx-theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/your_new_js_file.js

2) Create file app/design/frontend/{COMPANY}/{THEME_NAME}/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

3) Add the following in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head><link src="Magento_Theme/js/your_new_js_file.js"/></head>
</page>
```

4) I had to run setup:static-content:deploy and set permissions to server writable folders as well.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
##### Don't run the following command in a production environment. Research the best permissions approach in your scenario. This is for local environments only
chmod -R 777 pub/static generated/ var/ app/etc/
```