# How to write direct link of js in magento

Tags: magento2, xml

In magento 1 in xml

```
<script src="http://www.abc/aa/abc.js"></script>
```

In magento 2 i am trying to ad like this in my xml but its not adding how can i add js using link without download and save it. I want this js only in my custom page

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it through the admin area.

`Go to Stores > Configuration > Design` and then in the `HTML Head` tab you can add miscellaneous scripts there.
eg.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i want to add that js in only one custom page

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104684/how-to-add-external-js-in-magento2/104687#104687

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using template call

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::before.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

add template file before.phtml add below code

```
 <script src="http://www.abc/aa/abc.js" />
```