# how to set external js dependency for internal js in magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, google-map

In **default_head_blocks.xml** I've loaded following jquery.

```
<link src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"/>
<link src="js/main.js" order="101"/>
```

Now my situation I want map js loaded to be first but it's not working I've set the order parameter in my custom js but it's not working with external js, Even I tried with **requirejs**   but I'm getting following error in console.

**js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null(…)**

So what can be solution here??

**EDIT**
Even If I place it like following

```
<link src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" src_type="url" />
```

This won't change anything in order...I want this file to be loaded before my custom file called.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104684/how-to-add-external-js-in-magento2

Comment: Appending src_type="url" won't help

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

You need to add this **src_type="url"**

Comment: Appending src_type="url" won't help