# How to solve jquery issues in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs-config.js

I am using Magento 2.2.3 and I have created customtheme

But in my website scripts are not working properly.It gives me below error:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

[image]

I have added requirejs-config.js file in below path:

app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_catalog

But it still gives me same error.

So how can i solve this issue

Comment: do you use this  `require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
     //your js code here  
 });` as the main bracket of your script?

Comment: have done static content deploy properly ? and have u provide permissions to pub?

Comment: Yes I tried it too but still i got no solutions. Same error.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I have deployed content as well and my pub/static folder have permissions '777'

Comment: can you please check header that jquery library is being included or not ?

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to do that can you please tell me where to find that?

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya, just check view page source or click cltr+u and then check jquery library exist or not

Comment: @shashank I think require.js is included

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya, not require.js.. look for jquery.js

Comment: @shashank I can't find it anywhere so that means it is not included

Comment: yes..if jquery library not included..then surely that error would happen

Comment: So do you have any solutions?

Comment: can you please add jquery library in your theme head using theme layout file?

Comment: you have to put this code <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  in your theme layout default_head_blocks.xml  file. You can use this link as help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104684/how-to-add-external-js-in-magento-2

Comment: But won't it affect other js in website?

Comment: It should  not affect other js.. but you try it once ..have you tried it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81505/discussion-between-chintan-kaneriya-and-shashank).