# Eliminating JS and CSS build processes

Tags: magento2.2, js-css

We're trying to eliminate the entire process on making the build of JS and CSS.
What we exactly want is that we will create entire JS and CSS files manually and load them as a part of footer(No Magento process involvement) like we do in static websites. Is there any way we can stop Magento from even considering the JS and CSS files. All JS and CSS will not be even the part of build/deploy process and it will be served from CDN. We won't even have JS/CSS files in Magento folders.

Your help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example does something like this not work? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104769/70343

Comment: No it is not like that, we're not trying to JS currently that we will do just like a static webpage but what want to do here is that stop the magento to load any JS or CSS. It must only be responsible for HTML and PHP but when on frontpage a web page will open it will have one jS and CSS(Which will be generated manually) files coming from CDN.