# How to stop calling paypal objects file on home page?

Tags: magento2, javascript, payment-methods, requirejs-config.js

We don’t want to make a call out to PayPal (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js) file when loading the homepage.
We should only be making calls to PayPal on the cart page and checkout.

**Module Name**: Magento_Paypal

> File Path:
>   vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            orderReview: 'Magento_Paypal/order-review',
            paypalCheckout: 'Magento_Paypal/js/paypal-checkout'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        paypalInContextExpressCheckout: 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout'
    },
    shim: {
        paypalInContextExpressCheckout: {
            exports: 'paypal'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try overwriting that Require JS file so it only loads on the pages you wish. `*` means load regardless of element, you can replace with a selector or selectors meaning the script will only load if those selectors are present.

This may work:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '.checkout-index-index, .checkout-cart-index': {
            orderReview: 'Magento_Paypal/order-review',
            paypalCheckout: 'Magento_Paypal/js/paypal-checkout'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        paypalInContextExpressCheckout: 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout'
    },
    shim: {
        paypalInContextExpressCheckout: {
            exports: 'paypal'
        }
    }
};
```

I say *may* because I haven't tried this with multiple selectors. If it doesn't support multiple selectors you could add it twice with a different selector each time.

Answer (score 1):

A slight correction to Nagaraju's code:
Tested and verified on Magento 2.3.x and 2.4

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
               <referenceBlock name="paypal.express-in-context.component" remove="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with one of my co-developer followed below step.

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
         <referenceBlock name="paypal.express-in-context.component" remove="true" />
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert this directly via magento admin interface in the layout update xml field. works fine for me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rest of the solutions did not work for me on Magento 2.3.4 and ended up with website not loading.

Had to set the **Enable In-Context Checkout Experience** setting to **NO**

Setting found in *Stores > configuration > Sales > Payment methods > Paypal Express Checkout > Configure*

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <referenceBlock remove="true" name="paypal.express-in-context.component"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

You need to change the "*`<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">`*".
It's works for me. *Magento2.3.5*