# If script is includeed from default_head_blocks.xml error is noticed

Tags: magento2, addtocart, requirejs

I am developing a site in magento 2.3 flurys.digifrizz.com If script is included through default_head_blocks.xml there are lots of require js error noticed

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
        <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js" />
        <script src="bootstrap/popper.min.js" />
        <script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js" />
        <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" />
        <script src="scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js" />
        <script src="aos/aos.js" />
        <script src="js/classie.js" />
        <script src="js/selectFx.js" />
        <!-- <remove src="requirejs/require.js" /> -->
        <css src="owl-carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
        <css src="owl-carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css" />

        <css src="scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
        <css src="css/sidebar.css" />

        <css src="aos/aos.css" />

        <css src="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <css src="line-awesome/css/line-awesome.css" />

        <css src="fonts/fonts.css" />

        <css src="css/cs-select.css" />
        <css src="css/cs-skin-elastic.css" />

        <css src="css/style.css" />

        <css src="css/animate.css" />

    </head>
</page>
```

Can you please help me how to solve this problem

Comment: You got this error after content deploy?

Comment: yes after using custom_home.xml template

Comment: You are create custom extension and add custom_home.xml in it and try to add js right?

Comment: Its a custom theme yes and added this in default_head_blocks.xml

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97761/magento-2-how-to-call-a-js-file-on-homepage

Comment: Yes but I am getting lots of error if script is included like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95850/discussion-between-somdeb-mukherjee-and-sanjay-gohil).

Answer (score 0):

To add JS to your theme you have several possibilities.

After add js in your `default_head_blocks.xml`  wrap your `JS` into the `requirejs`

Note - Copy  `jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js` and `aos.js` and move into 
              `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme-name/web/js` folder.

```
   Remove  <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js" /> from default_head_blocks.xml
```

Add `requirejs-config.js` in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme-name/` and add below content into it.

```
var config = {
  map: {
        '*': {
            'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min',
            'aos'        : 'js/aos/aos.js',                
            'scrollbar'  : 'js/scrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js',
            'bootstrap'  : 'js/bootstrap.min'
            'popper'     : 'js/popper.min.js', 
            'classie'    : 'js/classie.js',
            'selectex'   : 'js/selectFx.js', 
        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "owlcarousel": ["jquery"],
        "aos": ["jquery"],
        "scrollbar": ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
        "popper": ["jquery"],  
        "classie": ["jquery"],
        "selectex": ["jquery"],
    }
};
```

after that run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Let me know if you need any further help..!